# JNI, can't run ndk-build

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to run a simple factorial program written in C++, and link it to java UI.

This is my Java code

```
package com.lan.factorial;

public class FacLib
{

    public native static long fac(long n);
    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("FacLib");
    }
    public static long facI(long n)
    {
        return fac(n);
    }
}
```

`

This is my C++ code

```
#include <studio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "com_lan_factorial_FacLib.h"
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_lan_factorial_FacLib_fac(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jlong)
{

    jlong f = 1;
    jlong i;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
         f *= i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

this is my make file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_lan_factorial_main.cpp

LOCAL_MODULE := com_lan_factorial_FacLib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and I keep getting this error when I run ndk-build:

```
C:\Users\Lan\workspace\Factorial>"..\..\temp\android\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build"
make: *** No rule to make target `jni/com_lan_factorial_main.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_lan_factorial_FacLib/com_lan_factorial_main.o'.  Stop.
```

Yes, my NDK in a different folder so I have to use `..\..\`, but I do not think it is the problem. and I did run `javah`

Comment: since you are trying to use the JNI you should have the NDK installed, go in the `samples` directory and take a look at the `hello-jni` example, all that you need to know it's there.

Comment: i do have ndk install, if you look at the path, I have temp\android\android-ndk-r8b\

Comment: ...is your C++ file in `C:\Users\Lan\workspace\Factorial\jni\com_lan_factorial_main.cpp`?

Comment: yes, C++, Android.mk, and com_lan_factorial_main.h are in jni folder

Comment: never I am dumped, I label my file as main.cpp instead of com_lan_factorial_main.cpp. But now I got this error: make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_lan_factorial_FacLib/main.o] Error 1

Comment: nevermind guyz, I have include <studio> support to be <stdio>, lol stupid mistake. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo) pointed out correctly, the name of your `.cpp` file name was not correctly listed in `Android.mk`.

Now you have a compilation problem in line 4:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_lan_factorial_FacLib_fac(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jlong)
                                                                                    ^
```

You lost the parameter name **n**, but you use it in line 9:

```
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

Note that it's OK to skip the name of the second parameter of type `jclass` which you never use.

I am not sure your compiler found the `com_lan_factorial_FacLib.h` file, but that's not a problem: you can remove this `#include` statement altogether, your code does not use it.